# \u200b (Zero width space) characters in my JS code. Where did they come from?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, netbeans, unicode

I am developing a front end of a web app using NetBeans IDE 7.0.1. Recently I had a very nasty bug, which I finally fixed.

Say I have code

```
var element = '<input size="3" id="foo" name="elements[foo][0]" />';
$('#bar').append(element);
```

I noticed that something gone wrong when I saw that `size` attribute doesn't work in Chrome (didn't checked in other browsers). When I opened that element in Inspector, it was interpreted as something like

```
<input id="&quot;3&quot;" name="&quot;elements[foo][0]&quot;" 
    size="&quot;foo&quot;" />
```

Which was rather strange. After manually retyping the `element` string character-in-character, the bug was gone. When I undo'ed that change I noticed that Netbeans alerted me about some Unicode characters in my old code. It was `\u200b` - a zero width spaces after each '=', between '][' and in the end of the string. So the string appeared normal because zero width spaces wasn't displayed, but after escaping them my string was

```
'<input size=\u200b"3" id=\u200b"foo" name=\u200b"elements[foo]\u200b[0]" />\u200b'
```

Now where the hell did I get them?

I'm not sure where did I copied the code of `element` from, but it's definitely one of the following:

- Other pane of Netbeans Editor with HTML template file;
- Google Chrome Inspector, 'Copy as HTML' action;
- Google Chrome source view page (very doubtfully).

But I can't reproduce the bug with neither of that.

I use Netbeans 7.0.1 and Google Chrome 13.0 under Windows 7. No keyboard switchers or anything like it is running. Also I'm using Git for version control, but I didn't pulled that code, so it is very unlikely that Git is to blame. It can't be a stupid joke of my colleagues, because they are quite well-mannered.

Any suggestions who messed up my code?

Comment: Scary. I hope you track it down.

Comment: Thanks, @RichieHindle. I gave up on tracking it down by my own, hope the community will help. After all it's not that scary after I know how to fix it (scan sources for "\u200b" appearences). But I'm curious where does that came from.

Comment: @Hnatt: is your second line of code calling jQuery? If yes Can you try to "alert" the content of var element using escape() and/or encode() before using it further; can you try to recode your append bypassing jQuery (use getElementsByTagName(), append()) to clearly falsify jQuery as the source of all evil?

Comment: @Hnatt/2: if jQuery, would you advise version .... maybe someone trying to reproduce this is using a different version

Comment: @MikeD it's jQuery 1.4.2, but it has nothing to do with the bug, because those Zero Length Spaces was pasted **in my code**, not generated by script. What I am trying to figure out is how did I manage to copy it there.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here's a stab in the dark.

My bet would be on Google Chrome Inspector. [Searching](http://www.google.com/codesearch#/&exact_package=chromium) through the Chromium source, I spotted [the following block of code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/ElementsTreeOutline.js&exact_package=chromium&q=%22%5Cu200b%22&l=1384)

```
    if (hasText)
        attrSpanElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("=\u200B\""));

    if (linkify && (name === "src" || name === "href")) {
        var rewrittenHref = WebInspector.resourceURLForRelatedNode(node, value);
        value = value.replace(/([\/;:\)\]\}])/g, "$1\u200B");
        attrSpanElement.appendChild(linkify(rewrittenHref, value, "webkit-html-attribute-value", node.nodeName().toLowerCase() === "a"));
    } else {
        value = value.replace(/([\/;:\)\]\}])/g, "$1\u200B");
        var attrValueElement = attrSpanElement.createChild("span", "webkit-html-attribute-value");
        attrValueElement.textContent = value;
    }
```

It's quite possible that I'm simply barking up the wrong tree here, but it looks like zero-width spaces were being inserted (to handle soft text wrapping?) during the display of attributes. Perhaps the "Copy as HTML" function had not properly removed them?

---

#### Update

After fiddling with the Chrome element inspector, I'm almost convinced that's where your stray `\u200b` came from. Notice how the line can wrap not only at visible space but also after `=` or chars matched by `/([\/;:\)\]\}])/` thanks to the inserted zero-width space.

[image: chrome inspector screenshot]

Unfortunately, I am unable to replicate your problem where they inadvertently get included into your clipboard (I used Chrome 13.0.782.112 on Win XP).

It would certainly be worth [submitting a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) should your be able to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: I don't see how can it insert `\u200b` between `=` and `"`. But in case of `][` it's seems quite possible, as far as I can see. Thanks Shawn!

Comment: The line just before the quoted code block does `.appendChild(document.createTextNode("=\u200B\""))`. My guess is that's where the `\u200B` after the `=` happens. Will update answer to include that line.

Comment: And I couldn't reproduce it. But, anyways, thanks for your answer. Searching Chromium code seems the best way to catch that bastard.

Comment: I'm still wondering why can't I reproduce it. Maybe there's some `if(theMoonIsFull)` condition. I'll accept your answer in a day if there will be no other answer with the bug actually **reproduced**.

Comment: I accept your answer in sign of appretiation of your efforts (And because it seems really consistent) Let the way I managed to copy those characters remain a mystery. Maybe the main reason is my crooked hands and a bit of bad luck. Must say that the moon actually **was** full at the time this happened, so I'll wait till next one and try to replicate the bug!

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me when I copied source code from another site into my editor.
If your using visual studio code or Atom editor, this will highlight those pesky characters zero-width space `\u200b)` etc.

[image]

- VSCode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins
- Atom editor: https://atom.io/packages/highlight-bad-chars
- Sublime Text: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Gremlins

Answer (score 7):

As Mr [Shawn Chin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115845/shawn-chin) has addressed it already. I just happened to replicate the issue while I was copy pasting jquery code from a webpage.

When it happened: Copying text from Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.118 m ( not tested with other browsers ) to Dreamweaver code window. This copied  unwanted characters along the code like this happening here

you copied text from a webpage as

```
$('.btn-pageMenu').css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'block');​​​​​​
```

behind the scenes, this is what makes that line

```
<code><span class="pun">&#8203;</span><span class="pln">$</span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="str">'.btn-pageMenu'</span><span class="pun">).</span><span class="pln">css</span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="str">'display'</span><span class="pun">&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;,</span><span class="str">'block'</span><span class="pun">);&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;</span></code>
```

Copied to an advanced editor like those you mentioned or Dreamweaver gives errors in browser, probably failing of javascript code too

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Solution: When it happens, embrace the worth of notepad until this gets fixed by the big guys. It is more related to the editor then the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

After longer than 6 years I am getting the same issue but I am able to reproduce it.

I am learning JavaScript from this [blog](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/) which contains code snippets. Whenever I copy all the code from a snippet and paste it into the JavaScript editors of JS Fiddle or JS Bin I get some red tokens spread into the code. Here are screenshots of the first code snippet from the above blog post in the [JS Fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb1SO.png) and [JS Bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ1nG.png). Hovering the mouse over one of these red tokens shows up the tip: "\u200b" (the [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)).

I'm working on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and if I paste the code into one of my editors (Atom 1.22.1 or Geany 1.32) and then open the file in web browsers, I get the following errors in the console:

- Chrome 63 --> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
- Firefox 57 --> SyntaxError: illegal character

I hope this may help a bit to clarify why these zero-width spaces get copied into the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with '\u200b' zero-width space character in my current project. I need to work on JSON object returned from server. Email object with '[at]' need to be replaced with '@' character. Surprisingly, several of the objects had the email address littered with 'space' in and around the '@'.

Long story short, I checked using Postman and scrutinised the returned JSON as RAW. Here is the raw example:

```
johndoe[at]\u200bxyz.org
```

I could see the character '\u200b' on all those trouble email address. Since only few email addresses affected, I removed the character manually. The server gets the data from Sharepoint.