# Why would the existence of a CSS rule cause another not to match?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've tried creating the following HTML file in Chrome:

```
<style>
br {
}​

[required] {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: red;
}

</style>
<input required />
```

that is the complete content of the file. The `[required]` rule does not match and the `<input>` remains unstyled.

If the empty br rule is left out so that the file reads:

```
<style>

[required] {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: red;
}

</style>
<input required />
```

It works fine!

Why would the existence of the `<br>` rule before the `[required]` one cause `[required]` to not match?

Thanks.
(It works fine is jsfiddle, you need to actually create the files.)

Comment: I don't see this behavior in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvcAL/ looks fine to me. Are you able to replicate somewhere we could see?

Comment: Does it work fine if you create file and put it online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new line is invalid somehow. The code performs as expected when they are removed.

I've traced the problem to right after the closing bracket for `br`. here's what I get in vim:

```
<style>
br {
}<200b>

[required] {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: red;
}

</style>
<input required />
```

Apparently `<200b>` is the Unicode zero width space. I am not familiar with this character and don't know why it would be present in this file. Deleting it resolves the issue.

Comment: I've typed code from question into my editor, and created file. And I've got same problem as Adam.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović I am aware that there is an issue and I have traced it down. The question is how this odd character got there to begin with.

Comment: That's so strange. I have no idea how that got there. Great catch!

Comment: @matt3141 You're right, i didn't get it before last edit of your answer.

Comment: According to an answer to a question on [zero width space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055600/u200b-zero-width-space-characters-in-my-js-code-where-did-they-came-from), it may have been generated by Chrome Inspector.

Answer (score -1):

i think that the br is helping trick the browser - because their are more brackets...

i think you are missing something...

```
.required{} and
<input class="required">  


or 
#required{} and
<input id="required">
```

lets have the fiddle !

Comment: He don't use class or id named "required", but property "required" http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_required.asp

Comment: oops -  didn't catch that --- thanks - i see now.  seems to be working fine from my end.  maybe just forgot a bracket >?