# Detect enter in input elements of a certain class

Tags: jquery, class, keypress, enter

I need to detect when someone hits "enter" in text inputs with a specific class.

My jQuery is as follows:

```
$('input.large').keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.which ==13)
        console.log("pressed enter");
});
```

My HTML is something like this:

```
<tr><td> Personal Name </td></tr>
<tr><td> <input type='text' class='large'> </td></tr>

<tr><td> Email</td></tr>
<tr><td> <input type='text' class='large'> </td></tr>
```

When I've given the fields IDs and tried `$('#elementid').keypress` it worked. But this isn't working. I get no console output. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you put your code within document ready handler?

Comment: I have. Other code just before and after this is working fine.

Comment: Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: should work - http://jsfiddle.net/vYfGQ/

Comment: I know... there's nothing wrong with this code. And I can't paste all the code because it's too much, there must be something stopping it.

Comment: Try pasting `console.log("Inside keypress");` inside the key-press method() and before `if` part and see if you are getting any console output, just validate your `key press` if working or not!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use live ([.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) events in `document` with `keydown` (I think this is better). It'll allow you detect `keydown` in current and future elements that matches with a selector.

**HTML**:

```
<strong>Personal Name</strong>
<input type='text' class='large' /><br />

<strong>Email</strong>
<input type='text' class='large' />
​
```

**JS** (jQuery 1.7+):

Note: `.which`, `.code`, `.charCode` and `.keyCode` is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). Use the following new solution:

```js
jQuery(document).on('keydown', 'input.large', function(ev) {
    if(ev.key === 'Enter') {
        // Will change backgroundColor to blue as example
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#EFF';

        // Avoid form submit
        return false;
    }
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/david_proweb/fjgvhubn/2/

Comment: where should I put this though? I tried it inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});` and also outside it, but either way there was a syntax error.

Comment: Where is this syntax error? **Try it**: create an exclusive `<script>` element with this content on end of file. If it doesn't works, use Chrome and enable debug to know where is the error exactly.

Comment: There is a hidden (zero-width) unicode character at the end of the line: ​`\u200b`.
Seems like a line wrap character: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077279/295246 I know this is old, but I thought I'd share! :)

Comment: Properties `which`, `code`, `charCode` and `keyCode` is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent, please add actual information to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

check this one: **http://jsfiddle.net/EJyyr/**

used this html:

```
<tr><td> Personal Name </td></tr>
<tr><td> <input type='text' class='large' id='a'> </td></tr>

<tr><td> Email</td></tr>
<tr><td> <input type='text' class='large' id='b'> </td></tr>
```

and this is the jQuery `which logs the input text id`

```
$('.large').keypress(function (e) {
   if(e.which ==13)
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David Rodrigues for your explanation. It helped a lot. I had to upgrade my JQuery library and the .live() function stopped to work properly.

You can use it to the following

Select all check box inputs of a form when click on select_all_checkboxes input type checkbox:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#select_all_checkboxes", function(){
    var chk = this.checked;
    $('input[id=selectAll]').each(function(){
        this.checked = chk;
    });
});
```

Call a function "checkMail" when the user left the field using tab ou clicking of the any field that has a class name "email":

```
jQuery(document).on("blur", 'input.email', function(event){
    var email = $(this).val();
    if (!checkMail(email)) {
        alert("Invalid email.");
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: While your answer is appreciated, a comment on another user's answer should be just that.