# Salesforce custom button returning 'Unexpected Token ILLEGAL?

Tags: javascript, unicode, salesforce

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")}

/*Getting the Running User Details*/
var result = 
sforce.connection.query(
    "SELECT Advisor__c " + 
    "FROM User " +
    "WHERE Id = '{!$User.Id}'"
);

/*Grab the Records returned by executing the above SOQL Query*/
var userDetails = result.getArray("records")[0];

/*Initializing the Contact record for Update*/
var contactToUpdate = new sforce.SObject("Contact");

contactToUpdate.Id = "{!Contact.Id}";

/*If the Running User is an "Advisor" then set the
Contact With and associated fields*/
if(userDetails.Advisor__c === true){
contactToUpdate.Contact_With__c = "{!$User.Id}";
contactToUpdate.Last_Advisor_Touch__c = new Da​te();
}
/*If the Running User isn't an "Advisor" then set the
Contact With 2 and associated fields*/
else{
contactToUpdate.Contact_With_2__c = "{!$User.Id}";
contactToUpdate.Last_Non_Advisor_Touch__c = new Date();
}

var result = sforce.connection.update([contactToUpdate]);

if(result[0].success === true){
location.reload();
}
else{
alert(result[0].errors.message);
}
```

I added a custom check box field to our user profiles titled "Advisor" The code is suppose to distinguish which field to update based on if a user has this box checked or not. If yes update this field, If not update that field. Instead though it's returning a 'Unexpected Token ILLEGAL. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a special hidden character in following line
`contactToUpdate.Last_Advisor_Touch__c = new Da​ te();`

in word Date
If you just rewrite it it should work. 
Specifically you have the infamous [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) between Da and te probably comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055600/u200b-zero-width-space-characters-in-my-js-code-where-did-they-came-from). To eliminate such things you can use [this tool](http://jsbeautifier.org/) or [this one](http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php)