# Getting the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I have tried to fix the issue but failed to do so. Finally posting my script here. 
Let me know the where the issue is

```
function displayNumber(myNumber) {
  console.log(myNumber);
}

​function displayCallBack(callNumber, callback) {
  callback(callNumber);    
} 

displayCallBack(30, displayNumber);
```

Comment: You have a weird Unicode character (`\u200b`) before your second function. Try posting your code into your dev console and you'll see it as a dot (at least in Chrome).

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. please read the guidelines to get great answers to your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\u200b (Zero width space) characters in my JS code. Where did they came from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7055600/371184)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have some whitespace characters in your code \u200b. These whitespace characters are causing your issues.

[\u200b (Zero width space) characters in my JS code. Where did they come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055600/u200b-zero-width-space-characters-in-my-js-code-where-did-they-came-from)

Edit:
Here is your code without those whitespace characters and it works fine.

```
function displayNumber(myNumber){
    console.log(myNumber);
}

function displayCallBack(callNumber, callback){
     callback(callNumber);
}

displayCallBack(30,displayNumber);
```