# Creating a model in nodejs return unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a simple model in nodejs but got the following error

```
var model = {​​​​​​​
                 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
```

**Model**

```
function getAllSales(limit) {
    const sales = [];
    var model = {​​​​​​​
        "id": ​​"1",
        ​"​​​​​​products": ​​[{​
            "id": ​"​1",
            ​​"value": "​​10"​​
        }, ​​​ {​​
            "id": "​​2",
            "​​value": "​​20"
        }],
        "​​​​​​​total": ​​ "30.00",
        "date": "2017-10-02"
    };
    sales.push(model);

    return sales.slice(0, limit);
}
```

Comment: any weird white-space character maybe?

Comment: Looks like you have some strange white space / non-printable character there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055600/u200b-zero-width-space-characters-in-my-js-code-where-did-they-came-from

Comment: Your code is full of [`U+200B`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) characters. Try to paste it in chrome console.

Comment: Erase the line and rewrite it manually, like the others say it is probably a random non-visible character messing with it

Comment: What makes this question downvotable ?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a ton of invisible characters there causing issues. Delete that `var` line, redo it, and you should be fine.

The specific character is [8203](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm), a zero-width space, which is not valid JavaScript.