# Adding a class to every second item with that has specific class

Tags: javascript, for-loop, jshint

It works but JShint gives me an error on last line **Unexpected '​'.** This is why I'm unable to compile using gulp and the whole thing crashes.

```
var yearData = document.querySelectorAll(".timeline-years .have-data");
for (var i = 0, length = yearData.length; i < length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    yearData[i].classList.add("bottom-year");
  }
}​
```

Not sure whats the fatal flaw here?

Comment: When I copy + paste your code into JSFiddle, there's an invalid `\u200b` character after the last `}`. Perhaps this is related: [\u200b (Zero width space) characters in my JS code. Where did they come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055600/u200b-zero-width-space-characters-in-my-js-code-where-did-they-come-from)

Comment: Btw, you can probably do this [just with CSS only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: @Bergi it doesnt contain only .have-datas, it has elements without the class so needs to skip those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing [Zero-width space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) on line 5.

Remove this and your code will run.

Comment: I feel like rather than an answer, this situation warrants more of a "comment and close as *typo*". Just for future reference.