# Helm integer intended to be string value parsed with escape character "\u200"

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have this `Secret` resource yaml:

```yaml
...
stringData:
  imageTag: {{ .Values.image.tag | quote }}

...
```

In the value file:

```yaml
image:
  tag: "65977​45"
...
```

When running the `helm template` command results to a generated yaml file with the value:

```yaml
...
stringData:
  imageTag: "65977\u200b45"
...
```

Seems like a bug in helm. To get around this issue, I have to do this:

```yaml
...
stringData:
  imageTag: "{{ .Values.image.Tag }}"

...
```

Is there a better solution? I am using helm version `2.15.2`

Comment: Add the result of `helm version` to the question body.

Comment: version is `2.15.2`

Comment: The issue is when I copy paste the tag value from Jenkins. Although the value are the same when doing a file compare but I think there are some hidden characters.

Comment: Yes, you're right. `\u200b` represents zero width space. Take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077279/11032044