# unnecessary %E2%80%8B added in the url

Tags: reactjs

I set my base URL in axios.create() method and consume it another pages. but it added unnecessary '%E2%80%8B' in the URL. Is there any way to avoid this issue?
This is my code block:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiVersion = 1;
export const baseURL = ('https://localhost:50001')

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
});

export const urls = {
    unit: {
    get_all: `/​api/v${apiVersion}/Unit/get-all-units`,
    get_by_key: `api/v${apiVersion}ion}/Unit/get-unit`,
    post: `/api/v${apiVersion}/Unit/save-unit`,
    put: `/api/v${apiVersion}/Unit/update-unit`,
    delete: `​/api​/v${apiVersion}​/Unit​/delete-unit​`
  }
}
```

This axios i intended to use my another component in this way:

```
const getAllUnits = async () => {
    try {
      await axios
        .get(urls.unit.get_all)
        .then(res => {
          setRecords(res.data.data);
          setIsLoaded(true)
        })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

But it showing this error. Please help me out.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP9Ya.png)

Comment: the base url should be `http://localhost:50001` instead of https

Comment: Seems like you have a [zero width space character](https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/151) in your url. So, to fix it, you need to retype (not copy paste) the urls in the code.

Comment: There are few editor extensions to see these characters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56501961/2873538. Or try https://stackoverflow.com/q/11305797/2873538

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an invisible character in your template string(s), called "zero width space" ([see this table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)). You may have accidentally inserted it or copied it from somewhere else. Try deleting and retyping the template strings entirely to make sure you get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks. i found my problem. but is there any solution? i have a lot of urls. to manually typing this is annoying

Comment: You could try pasting your code into a simple text editor (like Notepad, if you're on Windows) and then paste it back into your code editor. You could also try doing a find-and-replace using your code editor: copy the start of the offending string ("`api", including the backtick), paste it into the "find" field, then type in "`api" in the "replace" field.