# String length shows that this string's length is 7, but actually string length is 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My constant declaration is like that:

```
const table = req.params.table;
```

And when I send a request with "circle" as table param, `table.length` returns as 7.

I tried to make this like that:

> table.toString().trim().length

But it's still showing that this word's length is 7.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is `table`?

Comment: Why not show us what is in req.params?

Comment: console.log(req.params) return as { table : '​circle' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per what I have observed in the data that's being received there's an extra `U+200B zero width space` character. That's the main reason why the length is not coming as expected.

I have copied the `{ table : '​circle' }` from the comments and tried to execute the same in browser console, this is how it looks in the console.

[image]

In the below snippet also the same thing is happening i.e., `\u200b` which is zero width space unicode character is being added

```js
let x = { table : '​circle' }

console.log(x.table.length);
```

In order to avoid this issue you can do something like below

```js
let x = { table: '​circle' }

const { table } = x;
const table2 = table.replace('\u200b', '');

console.log(table.length);
console.log(table2.length);
```

For more info please refer

- [Remove zero-width space characters from a JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305797/remove-zero-width-space-characters-from-a-javascript-string)
- [\u200b (Zero width space) characters in my JS code. Where did they come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055600/u200b-zero-width-space-characters-in-my-js-code-where-did-they-come-from)

Answer (score 0):

You need an assigment, because strings are immutable.

```
 table = table.toString().trim()
```

Comment: const tbl = table.toString().trim()
                console.log(tbl.length);

the output is still 7

Comment: where do you the the value from?

Comment: From API request.

Comment: please add the content of `table` as you get it.