# NodeJS invalid syntax in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token line 5
```

I cant seem to find what is missing or where the syntax is wrong

```js
const getData = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const connection = createConnection();
        const sqlQuery = fs.readFileSync('./file.sql').toString();
      ​
        connection.connect((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error connecting to Db:' + err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Database connection established.');
            connection.query(sqlQuery, (err, results, fields) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                connection.end((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log('Database connection closed.');
                    resolve(results);
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: And _"line 5"_ is where?

Comment: in between const sql query and connection.connect

Comment: You seem to have a hidden character the example. `​` shows as a red dot  in prettier. Try deleting the characters in between `toString();` and `connection`?

Comment: The `Promise()` won't resolve or reject when `.connect()` fails.

Comment: There's a "zero width space" (`\u200B`) in line 5

Comment: Good catch Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `line 5` by backspacing it so that your new line 5 is now    `connection.connect((err) => {`
There is thing called an "invisible character" that can be created when copying and pasting code. Notice that when you hover over the syntax error in the dev tools on the browser it gives you `\u200b`. Here is another article discussion on stackoverflow that may be helpful:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055600/u200b-zero-width-space-characters-in-my-js-code-where-did-they-come-from)